# The relation of $\alpha$ having index of nilpotence $k>0$ and being (with $\sigma_{1}$) 1-1 and onto.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations, nilpotence, vector-space-isomorphism

let V be a vector space over a field $F$and let $\alpha \in End(V)$ be nilpotent,  having index of nilpotence $k>0.$Show that $\sigma_{1} + \alpha \in Aut(V).$

where $\sigma_{c}$ is defined as $\sigma_{c}(v) = cv.$

**My thoughts:**

By definition of $Aut(V),$ I should show that $\sigma_{1} + \alpha $ is a linear transformation, 1-1 and onto.

For the linear transformation part, I have shown that:$\forall x,y \in V$ and $\forall \gamma \in F, (\sigma_{1} + \alpha)(x + \gamma y) = (\sigma_{1} + \alpha )(x) + \gamma (\sigma_{1} + \alpha)(y).$
   I did not use the hypothesis that $\alpha$ is nilpotent in any step of this proof ....  or should this step include the usage of this hypothesis?

Second for proving 1-1, I stopped at $x + \alpha(x) = y + \alpha(y)$ but then what? how can I show that $x = y$?

For the onto part, I do not know why if we are given an element $v \in V,$ why we are sure that there exists an element $w \in V$ such that $(\sigma_{1} + \alpha)(w) = v$, could anyone help me in proving this please?

Comment: Any sum of endomorphisms is an endomorphism (i.e. this will always be a linear transformation). So you are correct that you shouldn't use the nilpotence there.

One tactic for second is to rearrange as $x-y = \alpha(y-x)$. Can you do anything with this equation to conclude that $x$ must equal  $y$?

For onto, maybe start with $w = v+$ something. Can you choose 'something' to get the desired equation?

Comment: @user113102 will the nilpotence help me in the 1-1 part? or in the onto part? or in both?

Comment: It will be necessary to use it in both.

Comment: @user113102 I do not know how to do this :(

Comment: Try first the easier case: assume $\alpha^2 = 0$. What happens if I hit both sides of the equation $x-y = \alpha(y-x)$ with $\alpha$?

For onto, look at $w = v- \alpha(v)$.

Comment: in the 1-1 case, I will get $\alpha(x-y) = 0$ which means that x=y as $\alpha $ is a homomorphism ..... should I complete by induction@user113102

Comment: It's not because $\alpha$ is a homomorphism... but from the fact that you know $x-y = \alpha(y-x) = 0$, so $x=y$. And it won't be by induction probably, but a similar trick will work in the more general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall this basic algebraic identity when $ab=ba$:

$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2+\cdots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}).$$

And $\sigma_1$ commutes with everything, so we have

$$\sigma_1^k-(-\alpha)^k=(\sigma_1+\alpha)\big(\sigma_1^{k-1}-\sigma_1^{k-2}\alpha+\sigma_1^{k-3}\alpha^2-\cdots+\sigma_1(-\alpha)^{k-2}+(-\alpha)^{k-1}\big)$$

which simplifies to

$$\sigma_1-0=\sigma_1=(\sigma_1+\alpha)\Big(\sigma_1-\alpha+\alpha^2-\cdots+(-\alpha)^{k-2}+(-\alpha)^{k-1}\Big).$$

Therefore, $\sigma_1+\alpha$ has an inverse, which is the factor on the right. Invertible means both one-to-one and onto.